# Display the value of a select list without a button

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the value to be displayed after the selection from the list is made, without the use of a button. I tried to implement an onChange event for the select list, and doing away with the button, but I can't get it to work. I'd like the value (1,2,3) to display below the select box after an option (a,b,c) is selected.

```
<script>
    function displayResult() {

        this.nextSibling.nodeValue = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <select id="mySelect" style="width:220px">
            <option value="1">a</option>
            <option value="2">b</option>
            <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayResult.call(this)">List Locations</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZkR2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JQuery you can do this:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id="mySelect" style="width:220px">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
    </select>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        $('#myDiv').html(this.value);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qv7cj/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    //do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready', function(){
            $('#mySelect').on('change', function(){
                console.log($('#mySelect').find('option:selected').attr('value'));
            })
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>`enter code here`
<form>
    <select id="mySelect" style="width:220px">
        <option value="1">a</option>`enter code here`
        <option value="2">b</option>
        <option value="3">c</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult.call(this)">List Locations</button>
</body>
</html>

pls try this
```